# How to send input to command prompt via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, git

I am running the following command via node js.

```
execSync('git push origin master');
```

When the command run, git prompt user for username and password, but I want to send the username and password through nodeJS.(As i'm not creating the command line app)

I need to send username and password with command as input like this:

```
execSync('git push origin master',{//attach username and password});
```

How can I do that?

PS: I cannot use git ssh.

Comment: Can you set up and use [ssh-key](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/)?

Comment: I want to do that with NodeJS. Do you have any idea, how can I do that?

Comment: If you set up an ssh-key it should work from anywhere, because ultimately Nodejs `exec`s `git` as a commandline in a child process, which will try to read your key from your `~/.ssh/id_pub` file.

Comment: and how to set key in ~/.ssh/id_pub ?

Comment: `ssh-keygen` generates it for you. The above [article has all the details](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/). [Or you can find many other great resources out there](http://google.com/search?q=how+to+ssh+key)